# Is there any browser extension/application which converts arxiv footnote references to URLs in PDFs?

Tags: arxiv

I'm reading ML papers where nearly every reference is on arxiv. It would be really nice if clicking on a footnote directly opened the paper, rather then sending me to the bottom of the PDF. I haven't been able to find anything using Google, but would be really surprised if nothing of the sort existed...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not *exactly* the functionality you want, but the [arXiv Bibliographic Explorer](https://github.com/mattbierbaum/arxiv-bib-overlay) from [arXivLabs](https://labs.arxiv.org/showcase/) may be useful. It is a browser extension that allows you to view the references and citations for a paper on the arXiv without having to e.g. search for the title of the paper on Google. If you have the PDF opened in one tab and the arXiv page in another, then you can quickly find hyperlinks to relevant papers through the search functionality.

I'm not aware of any software that can modify the target of a PDF hyperlink after the PDF has been compiled. At least in my field, the formatting and style of references is not standardized on the arXiv so I think it may be difficult to find a tool that can parse the necessary data in the general case

Comment: Not what I was looking for indeed but this is still super cool, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative I ended up finding: https://www.arxiv-vanity.com/ which renders arxiv links in HTML. It does show a direct link for every reference on hover! Unfortunately the rendering is quite bad sometimes, hopefully it keeps improving.